# How to add separate in hourly split graph in flot

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a graph which is split on hours and I want to show separator in between days means it should display separator line at every start day. like on 26th may 00:00 and then 27th may 00:00 rest of the graph will be shown as it is.
I am using flot library.

Comment: Do i have to assume everything? You have any Code? You can show us

Comment: Everything is common I haven't added anything different yet. I am looking for any option which can add some separator line in graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `markings` in your [grid options](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid):

```
var timestamp = new Date(2015, 5, 27).getTime();
markings: [ { xaxis: { from: timestamp, to: timestamp } }, ... ]
```

This will draw a line at midnight of May 27th 2015.
Use a loop to build the `markings` array if you need multiple lines.